# Differences between browsers php forms

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have this at the end of my form. I gives the user the option to continue to another form or upload the data that is on the current form.

My problem is that when I've tested in Chrome, IE, Safari, Android Internet. It all works well when you choose either option.

```
<form class="section4form" id="section4form" name="section4" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- Other sections of my form are here -->
<div class="myclass">
    <select id="selector" name="selector">
        <option value="">Please choose here to Finish Lead Gen or Continue to Section 5</option>
        <option value="http://mydomain/lead5.php">Finish & Upload</option>
        <option value="http://mydomain/lead4.php">Continue To Boiler Assessment</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn green" id="section4formsubmit" name="section4formsubmit" >Continue</button>
</form>
```

This is the jquery to go with the code at the bottom of my form page

```
<script>
document.forms.section4.onsubmit = function (event) {
    var e = event || window.event,
            form = e.currentTarget || e.sourceElement;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.action === "") return false;
    form.action = form.selector.value;
    form.submit();
};
</script>
```

My checking js file I add to validate the form

```
var LeadGen4 = function () {
var handleLeadGen4 = function () {
    var form4 = $('#section4form');
    var error4 = $('.alert-danger', form4);
    var success4 = $('.alert-success', form4);
    form4.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            householdersigned: { 
                required: true
            },
            hasawgsigned: {
                required: true
            },
            assessordeclaration: {
                required: true
            },                
            assessorname: {
                minlength: 5,
                required: true
            },                
            typeofleadgen: {
                required: true
            }                
        },
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit
            error4.show();
            App.scrollTo(error4, -200);
        },
        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
            .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
            $(element)
            .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
        },
        success: function (label) {
            label
            .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set success class to the control group
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('.section4formsubmit').html(data);
            error4.hide();
        }
    });
}
return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        handleLeadGen4();
    }
};
} ();
```

My problem is that if a user has Firefox as their browser then this code below doesn't do anything. No matter which option is selected the choice is not progressing.

Comment: what says the javascript console?

Comment: How do I see this javascript console?

Comment: Different by browsers and operating systems - `CTRL + ALT + I`, `SHIFT + ALT + I`, `STRG + SHIFT + I` or `F12`, try these combinations

Comment: I found the inspect element, it rtells me there is a reference error `ReferenceError: data is not defined` on an attaced js file at line 47. Line47 is this line here `$('.section4formsubmit').html(data);` which is from this section of code `submitHandler: function (form) {
 $('.section4formsubmit').html(data);
 error4.hide();
 }` why would it work in other browsers and not firefox

Comment: 1. its not the full code, please update in your Question. 2. why you mixed normal JS with jQuery. Why you dont use not generally jQuery?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the validation js I use, the reference error points to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the line out! The line is redundant and does not make sense.

```
 submitHandler: function (form) {
      // >>>>>>>>> $('.section4formsubmit').html(data);
      error4.hide();
 }
```